# Two stage model with a randomly transformed independent variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, data-transformation

Hi all and thank you in advance for helping!

I have three variables: $y$ the dependent count variable, $x$ the independent positive continuous variable, $U$ is the observation unit (and I expect a random effect with it). I would like to test the hypothesis that the slope for $x$ is positive. I would normally use the following model:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \phi + \epsilon$, where

- $\phi$ is the observation unit-level random error and
- $\epsilon$ is the observation-level random error.

But I have a complication: at each observation unit, the original $X$ is transformed in some unknown order-preserving way, but not necessarily the same way at each observation unit. For example:

- At $U=$"A", $x=X/2$,
- At $U=$"B", $x=X^2$,
- At $U=$"C", $x=3X+3$

How would I test my hypothesis that the slope for $x$ is positive? Is it feasible?

Comment: If the transformation can be different at each point, there's no reason to expect continuity. I'm not sure how one even defines a slope in that context.

Comment: True, I cannot find a meaningful interpretation for slope here. I am only interested in the sign of the slope (directionally increasing or decreasing).